# Instagram pop up feature alike in swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, xib

I was wondering if anyone have any idea how to work out something similar to Instagrams's feature that when you keep pressed a picture in a profile, it pops up until you release the screen. I have been looking around and haven't really found an answer. I was trying to work with popovers but they're not allowed in iphone and most of the alternatives use storyboards. Basically the difference from what im looking for and a popoverpresentation is that I want the new screen to cover most of the screen, not from it to come from the button itself, if that makes sense, while I have the screen pressed. So basically does anybody know how to do this in swift using no storyboards? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean 3D Touch?

Comment: I assume thats what it is? My main question is how would you achieve that, is the new screen coming up a popover screen? as far as the 3d touch, i assume it could work similar with a long press so thats not my main concern

Comment: My mistake, I didn't know Instagram had the long press for those who don't have 3D touch. I'm not actually sure if it would be a popover it just a view on top of the view controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recreating Instagram longpress peek?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049135/recreating-instagram-longpress-peek)